How to re-trigger and the "Finish Setting Up Your iPhone" notification in iPhone Settings and resume setup (iOS 17.5.1)?
Just got a new iPhone 15 with iOS 17.5.1 and started setting it up but I had to put it down before I could finish and now the "Finish Setting Up Your iPhone" notification badge and menu in Settings are both gone.
Is there a way I can get back to the "Finish Setting Up Your iPhone?" I don't remember which setup items I completed and which items I didn't.

If you haven't really used the iPhone for much, perhaps an Erase All Content And Settings action will get you to where you need to go as it wipes the iPhone to a new, unused state.
